# Configure error: could not find the zlib library

Tags: software-installation, error-handling, configure, virtualenv, pkg-config

I am trying to install lalsuite on ubuntu according to the instructions here:

https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install_lalsuite.html

Everything went smoothly until I ran

```
./00boot
./configure --prefix=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/opt/lalsuite --enable-swig-python
```

And the error I get is:

```
configure: error: could not find the zlib library
```

I am doing all this inside a virtual environment using virtualenv. I'm fairly certain I have the zlib library as I installed it with:

```
$ sudo apt install zlib1g
```

After a thorough search for a solution I found someone with the same problem:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217198&page=2&s=3d14badd56b8ebb236dfc0970ba19435

But I do not really understand their solution. My interpretation of their fix was to do the following:

First reinstall pkg-config:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

Then write the line suggested by the answer:

```
echo 'export PKG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pkg-config' >> ~/.bashrc
```

(I am doing all this inside the virtualenv by the way).

Then restart everything and try the same thing again:

```
./00boot
./configure --prefix=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/opt/lalsuite --enable-swig-python
```

Sadly the same error appears.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to install *-dev* package for `zlib1g` - it is named [`zlib1g-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/zlib1g-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

and it will install `zlib.pc` file for `pkg-config` [along with *zlib.h* header](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/zlib1g-dev/filelist).